# angularjs: what does ui-view do exactly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to get the Owl Carousel on one of my website pages but it's not showing up despite there being no errors in the console (I have included the correct JS/CSS files for Owl Carousel already so that's not the issue). I'm thinking my problem may have something to do with using

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

since if i take that away and replace it with the actual code for the view, it works, but that's not what I want because I'm creating a Single Page Application so I would want to use the ui-view directive

I have a config file linked to my main html file where I have

```
    $stateProvider.

state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',

}).

state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
}).
```

However, when i'm on the "about" page, the images for the carousel do not show up and I'm thinking it's because the css/javascript files are not being linked to the about page. I might be doing my config file wrong, but I don't know. Anybody have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: `ui-view` isn't going to break Owl Carousel, but Owl Carousel isn't angular compatible directly.  you'll need to make a Directive for Owl Carousel so that angular can delay loading it until you reach the page you are using it, rather than it loading on page start the way it is designed.

Comment: have u specified this <div ui-view="about.html"></div>

Comment: @claies making a directive worked! Thanks!

Comment: @ngLover i tried that but it didn't work, thanks tho